# Importing data with Power Query not using "|" delimiter correctly

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a script that basically imports a CSV report and cleans up the data and save it somewhere else on the network. Problem is that when it imports that report from a Linux server that uses a "|" as a delimiter, it incorrectly puts a couple users in a cell all mashed together.

I import the data with Power Query and filter the columns, and the various data that comes in with it.

Despite the data having the "|" delimiter all throughout the entire data sheet, there is always a couple cells that get put together as a random string like so:

`|Address||City|State|zip|205|305|6251|date|3650|store|lname|fname|ndc|address2||city2|state|zip|num|ber|cell|||bdate|90|Drug 200 MG|ndc|cost|pay|0.00|cost|pay|75.00|0.00|0.00|||||||||000|||200||||cost|M|0.00||||||||||||0.00|name1|name2|||||||||||||||||PRIMARY|On Hold|No Reason||||10:30|number|Will-Call|cost|drug TAB 200 MG|90|0|0|||||||||||||||||||0|Not Specified||0.00|0.00|0.00|`

*I had to remove sensitive data

Is there a way to go around this issue with the "|" delimiter? Or should I just try to use another special delimiter? I have to use special ones because there are commas, tabs, and spaces all over the report.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying certain records do not get split out into columns correctly when reading the .csv and instead show up as a single string? If you could create a sample .csv (with dummy data) that exhibits the issue, it would be a lot easier to evaluate.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you want to use `,` as a delimiter but there are also commas within your values (that should not be treated as a delimiter), you can wrap each value between a pair of double quotes (`"`), meaning any commas between the double quote would be treated as a literal rather than a delimiter. If you're using `Csv.Document()`, Power Query by default should behave as I've described.

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue extra linefeeds in the CSV?

If so, code like this will remove it (reading the file as binary, doing a replace on the linefeed, then converting it back to a normal table.)

```
Source = Text.Replace(Text.FromBinary(File.Contents("RAW.csv")), "#(lf)#(lf)","#(lf)"),
Source2 = Text.Replace(Source, "#(lf)""",""""),
Continue = Lines.FromText(Source2),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Continue, Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(","), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Converted to Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
```